# Unity 2D rotate car object towards next target point while moving

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

In 2D Unity project I have a car moving towards target points and I need the car to face the next target point.

Here is the code of moving car.

```
public class gr_car_move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Transform[] targets;

    private int currentTargetIndex = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (targets.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No targets assigned to script!");
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targets[currentTargetIndex].position, step);

        if (transform.position == targets[currentTargetIndex].position)
        {
            if (currentTargetIndex == targets.Length - 1)
            {
                // reached last target, stop cycling
                return;
            }
            currentTargetIndex = (currentTargetIndex + 1) % targets.Length;
        } 


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of Unity's [transform.forward](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html). Set it towards the direction you want it to face, and it's Z axis will face that way. if X axis is the forward of your car, then use [transform.right](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-right.html) and so on, I think you got the idea.

You can, for instance, use it like this:

```cs
transform.forward = targets[currentTargetIndex].position - transform.position;
```

Comment: thank you, but where exactly should I put this piece of code ?

Comment: you can use it everytime you set the `position`